# Getting 'Shutting down ExecutorService' (org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler) in kafka consumption

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

I sometimes get the error shutting down ExecutorService and then Consumer stopped. Kafka event is processed again, but the duplication appears, as this event is already processed until storing data. I have fixed the duplication with idempotence. But is there a way to prevent this shut down?
The properties of ExponentialBackOffPolicy:

```
backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(60000);
backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2.0);
backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(1000);
simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(60);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have a large retry interval and the consumer thread is blocked; retry in the listener adapter is deprecated now that the error handlers support back off and exception classification. The error handlers are also able to exit the retry whenever the container is stopped.

You use a suitably configured `DefaultErrorHandler` (2.8 and later) or a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` for earlier versions (versions before 2.7.10 are no longer supported for OSS users).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We use version 2.2.8RELEASE. Can we use SeekToCurrentErrorHandler or stay in retryTemplate and apply a reasonable retry interval?

Comment: 2.2.8 is 2.5 years old; the last 2.2.x release was 2.2.15 nearly a year ago. 2.2.x is long out of support. Current supported OSS versions are 2.7.10 and 2.8.3. https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support Exception classification is not supported in 2.2.x but if you don't need it, you can remove the retry template from the adapter.

Comment: I updated setMaxInterval as 30.000 ms. But still get same problem. `max.poll.interval.ms` is 10 min. Which values would be best for that case? Can it helpful to use statefulRetry and SeekToCurrentErrorHandler together?

Comment: That is what stateful retry is. It requires the STCEH. Without stateful retry, the max poll interval must be long enough to handle the aggregate retry delays for all records returned by the poll.